# A pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, multiple-indirection

I know I should know this, but it's late and my brain just won't put the pieces together.

This is as straight forward as a question can get:

I have a struct `item`. I want to create a pointer to an array of pointers to that item type.

Eg.

```
struct item {
    int data;
    string moreData;
};
```

I want to have an `ArrayPointer` that point's to an array. I want that array to contain in each element a pointer to an item.

How do I do this in C++, or more sepcifically where do I need to put how many dereferencing operators? I know how to declare basic (single indirection) pointers and am pretty fluent in their use.

I need information for the following steps if at all possible:

Declaring the `ArrayPointer`.

Initializing the `ArrayPointer` with a size s.

Initializing each element of `ArrayPointer` with `new item`.

eg:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    ArrayPointer[i] = // a new item
```

I feel like as soon as someone posts an answer I'm going to facepalm so hard I break my nose.

Comment: Do yourself a factor and use `std::vector<item>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<item>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then you need something like this

```
item **ArrayPointer = new item *[s];

for ( int i = 0; i < s; i++ )
{
    ArrayPointer[i] = new item; { i, "More Data" };
}
```

Or

```
item **ArrayPointer = new item *[s];

for ( int i = 0; i < s; i++ )
{
    ArrayPointer[i] = new item;
    ArrayPointer[i]->data = i;
    ArrayPointer[i]->moreData = "More Data";
}
```

To free the allocated memory you can in reverse order

```
for ( int i = 0; i < s; i++ )
{
    delete ArrayPointer[i];
}

delete [] ArrayPointer;
```

Otherewise if s is a constant then you may simply declare an array of pointers. For example

```
item * ArrayPointer[s];
for ( int i = 0; i < s; i++ )
{
    ArrayPointer[i]->data = i;
    ArrayPointer[i]->moreData = "More Data";
}
```

Comment: Thank's a lot Vlad. The bit I was missing was

`new item *[s]`

I've never seen that exact statement before. All of my attempts involved

`new *items[s]`


I just couldn't seem to find that specific syntax anywhere. Thanks again!

Comment: Sweet. I can also now initiate each element to NULL so I can keep the amount of memory I'm using minimal.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an array of `struct item *`, which are pointers to `item` structs.

An array of such pointers is a `struct item **`.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct item {
    int data;
    string moreData;
};

struct item * newItem(int data, string moreData) {
    struct item *result = (struct item *) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    result->data = data;
    result->moreData = moreData;
    return result;
}

struct item ** array;  // We don't know the size of the array in advance.

int main() {
    int arraySize = 3;  // We get this value from somewhere (user input?).
    array = (struct item **) malloc(3*sizeof(struct item *));
    // Now the array has been allocated. There is space for
    //  arraySize pointers.
    array[0] = newItem(5, "ant");    // Let's make some items. Note that
    array[1] = newItem(90, "bear");  //  newItem() returns a pointer to
    array[2] = newItem(25, "cat");   //  an item.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know how to do that, the problem is that I need the array to be pseudo-dynamic (I need to declare its size once during run-time).

The simple version would be:

`item *psDynamicArr;

psDynamicArr = new item[size];`

But in that case the array would contain items, I need it to contain pointers to items.

Comment: Okay, I've modified the code so that you don't declare its size in advance.

Answer (score 0):

file.h

```
struct item {
    int data;
    string moreData;
};

item ** array;
```

file.cpp

```
array = new item*[s];

for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    array[i] = new item;
    array[i]->data = 10;
    array[i]->moreData = "data";
}
```